# Is there a Vegan Society in China?

Tags: outreach

I haven't noticed any outreach in China to date. Which is odd because I can buy food made for vegans from Asia. Perhaps the information is not available in English or online.

Answer (score 4):

The [Vegan Society](https://www.vegansociety.com) has members based in China and all over the world, I had to verify but I see China listed in the drop down box in their become a [member page](https://www.vegansociety.com/get-involved/become-member).  You can even apply to become a [member advocate](https://www.vegansociety.com/get-involved/volunteering-vegan-society/community-network) within that country (cool!).

While I was traveling in Asia and Southeast asia, I did learn subtlety in different region's definition of Vegan and Vegetarian as well as reasons for being Vegan and Vegetarian...all that to say that would add context when searching for other vegans around the world.  I am based in the states and was surprised to find what some places don't consider meat.  In France my friend had to constantly explain that Vegan also excludes Fish.  The Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism_by_country#China) helped broaden my view.

Answer (score 2):

China is basically the polar opposite to many places in the west when it comes to meat eating. China's vegan lifestyle stems from religious influences. China's Buddhists are vegetarians (unlike those found in Tibet) and also the genetic make-up of the Chinese people make lactose-intolerance common.

What has also happened meat-eating has become a way to improve social-class and to show people that a certain financial level has been attained. Chinese are eating more meat because it is becoming more fashionable as time goes by.

The vegetarian lifestyles will continue to be there, but it becomes less 'in-vogue' with every year. I know personally if I ever go to Shenzen, I would walk right pass the KFC and go straight to a Buddhist temple and go see what veg fare they sell. I also realise, that by doing so, i will have traveled half-way around the world to go and eat what the local people consider, poor-people food

So yes, you can totally be a vegan in China. Just the amount of tofu products available is staggering, you are unlikely going to find societies outside the Buddhist tradition promoting it.

[Here is a video that you may find interesting.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjVkbvowNkA&t=1179s)